# Difference between hadn't been and hasn't been when both express past events

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

In the following sentence:

> The house was painted last weekend, it ..... painted for years.

should I use:

> A) *hasn't been*, or
> B) *hadn't been*?

This is confusing. My reasoning is as follows:
*Hadn’t been* is used to express the earlier of two events but there is only one event, namely, the painting, so why use it and not *hasn't been* to give the meaning?

Comment: "Hadn't been" refers to the past; ie. before the house was painted last weekend. "Hasn't been" would refer to the present and so would only be appropriate if the house had not been repainted recently.

Comment: If it hasn't been painted for years, how could it have been painted last week?

Answer (score 4):

“Hadn't been” is the correct answer.

If you were speaking about the situation *now*, you would use "hasn't been.”

> My bicycle hasn't been ridden for many years.

If you were speaking about the situation *at a particular time in the past*, referring to the entirety of time *before* that time, you would use "hadn't been.”

> When my cousin visited last week, my bicycle hadn't been ridden for many years.

(A reader would assume from the use of "hadn't been" that the arrival of your cousin led to the bicycle being ridden.)

The more recent event is the painting of the house that took place last weekend.  The earlier event is the painting years before.

Incidentally, I think your sentence should actually be two sentences, with a period after "weekend.”